# Separation into $|\Psi_{CM}\rangle$ and $|\Psi_{R}\rangle$ in abstract representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation

Consider a two-particle system with Hamiltonian

$$\hat H = \frac{(\hat{\mathbf p}^{(1)})^2}{2m_1} + \frac{(\hat{\mathbf p}^{(2)})^2}{2m_2} + V(\hat{\mathbf r}),$$

where $\hat{\mathbf r} = \hat{\mathbf r}^{(1)} - \hat{\mathbf r}^{(2)}$.

For a little background, let's see how we can handle this **in coordinate representation**. We first introduce a center of mass coordinate

$$\mathbf R = \frac{m_1 \mathbf r^{(1)} + m_2 \mathbf r^{(2)}}{m_1 + m_2},$$

in addition to the relative coordinate $\mathbf r$. It is then straightforward to show that

$$\mathbf r^{(1)} = \mathbf R + \frac{\mu}{m_1} \mathbf r, \quad \mathbf r^{(2)} = \mathbf R - \frac{\mu}{m_2} \mathbf r,$$

where $\mu = m_1 m_2 / (m_1 + m_2)$. Furthermore, using a vector calculus version of the chain rule, we find that

$$\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}} = (\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}} \cdot \mathbf R) \nabla_{\mathbf R} + (\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}} \cdot \mathbf r) \nabla_{\mathbf r} = \frac{\mu}{m_2} \nabla_{\mathbf R} + \nabla_{\mathbf r},$$

$$\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}} = (\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}} \cdot \mathbf R) \nabla_{\mathbf R} + (\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}} \cdot \mathbf r) \nabla_{\mathbf r} = \frac{\mu}{m_1} \nabla_{\mathbf R} - \nabla_{\mathbf r}.$$

Writing the Hamiltonian in coordinate representation and subtituting for $\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}}$ and $\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}}$, we obtain

$$\hat H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2M} \nabla_{\mathbf R}^2 -\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \nabla_{\mathbf r}^2 + V(\mathbf r),$$

where $M = m_1 + m_2$. Now we make the ansatz

$$\psi(\mathbf r^{(1)}, \mathbf r^{(2)}) = \psi_{\mathbf R}(\mathbf R) \psi_{\mathbf r}(\mathbf r),$$

and note that

$$\nabla_{\mathbf R} \psi_{\mathbf r}(\mathbf r) = (\nabla_{\mathbf R} \cdot \mathbf r) \nabla_{\mathbf r} \psi_{\mathbf r}(\mathbf r) = \mathbf 0, \quad \nabla_{\mathbf r} \psi_{\mathbf R}(\mathbf R) = (\nabla_{\mathbf r} \cdot \mathbf R) \nabla_{\mathbf R} \psi_{\mathbf R}(\mathbf R) = \mathbf 0$$

beacause

$$\nabla_{\mathbf R} \cdot \mathbf r = (\nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}} + \nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}}) \cdot \mathbf r = 0, \quad \nabla_{\mathbf r} \cdot \mathbf R = \frac{m_2 \nabla_{\mathbf r^{(1)}} - m_1 \nabla_{\mathbf r^{(2)}}}{m_1 + m_2} \cdot \mathbf R = 0.$$

Inserting our ansatz in the time-independent SE and then dividing both sides by the ansatz, we get

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2M} \frac{\nabla_{\mathbf R}^2 \psi_{\mathbf R}(\mathbf R)}{\psi_{\mathbf R}(\mathbf R)}  -\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \frac{\nabla_{\mathbf r}^2 \psi_{\mathbf r}(\mathbf r)}{\psi_{\mathbf r}(\mathbf r)} + V(\mathbf r) = E,$$

and this lets us separate the problem into two single-particle problems.

All of the above is fine, but **how can we do the same thing without resorting to the coordinate representation?** I watched a TA go through it, but I could not really buy into his argumentation. He defined the CM and relative position operators analogously to the above, and also defined corresponding momentum operators

$$\hat{\mathbf P} = \hat{\mathbf p}^{(1)} + \hat{\mathbf p}^{(2)}, \quad \hat{\mathbf p} = \frac{m_2 \hat{\mathbf p}^{(1)} - m_1 \hat{\mathbf p}^{(2)}}{m_1 + m_2}.$$

After computing the relevant commutators, this let him rewrite the Hamiltonian as

$$\hat H = \frac{\hat{\mathbf P}^2}{2M} + \frac{\hat{\mathbf p}^2}{2\mu} + V(\hat{\mathbf r}).$$

Now comes the part that I find fishy. He uses a product state ansatz $|\Psi\rangle = |\Psi_\text{CM}\rangle \otimes |\Psi_\text{R}\rangle \in \mathcal H^\text{(CM)} \otimes \mathcal H^\text{(R)}$, and then seemingly **redefines** the momentum operators according to

$$\hat{\mathbf P} \to \hat{\mathbf P}^\text{(CM)} = \hat{\mathbf P} \otimes \mathbb 1, \quad \hat{\mathbf p} \to \hat{\mathbf p}^\text{(R)} = \mathbb 1 \otimes \hat{\mathbf p},$$

and similarly for $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf r$. This then lets him separate the Hamiltonian into two parts,

$$\hat H = \hat H^\text{(CM)} + \hat H^\text{(R)},$$

with $\hat H^\text{(CM)}$ acting on $\mathcal H^\text{(CM)}$ and $\hat H^\text{(R)}$ acting on $\mathcal H^\text{(R)}$.

The conclusion is the same as what we found above in the coordinate representation. However, I find it very strange that we have to redefine the operators to act only on $\mathcal H^\text{(CM)}$ and $\mathcal H^\text{(R)}$, respectively. In the coordinate representation this simply fell out of the math, but in the abstract representation we seemingly have to introduce it ourselves, and I cannot see how that is valid at all.

**So, can someone explain the mathematical details of how to separate the above two-particle problem in the abstract representation?**

Comment: The "redefining" part is just changing the names, because he wants to use $\hat{\mathbf{P}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{p}}$ for the single variable operators; the important part is that in these coordinates these two-variable operators split as tensor products in the way shown. But I'm not sure if it's possible to show that without resorting to coordinates.

Comment: @Javier Ok, so would you say that the derivation in the abstract representation cheats a little bit by actually using knowledge obtained in the coordinate represantation?

Anyhow, should not the different representations of the SE be equivalent? The Dirac formalism certainly treats them as such, just expressed in different bases.